# Need help changing the opacity of a div element with a background image without also changing the opacity of the text?

Tags: html, css, rgba

I have a div element with a background image. I have some text within the div element will be displayed when you hover over the div element.  I want to reduce the brightness of the div element by 50% without changing the opacity of the text inside.  The only way I have found to do something similiar is to use the rgba function like so:

rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

However this only works on colors, I was wondering if there was a way to achieve the same effect without taking the text outside the div.
Im fairly new to HTML/CSS so I hope you guys may be able to help me. Thanks!

Comment: You can place the text on top of the DIV and you won't have to worry about it.

Comment: Please share some code what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

### *[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6A3zH/)*

You can use the `:after` pseudo to keep the background image and use opacity on it instead of the main element.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="have-img">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.have-img{
    position: relative;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 100px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.have-img:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/1000/200/') no-repeat center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```